# Question for web developers: using an image server for dynamic images

Tags: language-agnostic

Supposing you were designing an image gallery website that uses dynamic images. By dynamic, I mean that these images can be converted to different formats, scaled, cropped and watermarked on the fly. The dynamic images are retrieved from an image server (running separately from the web server) that keeps only one source image and responds to HTTP POST requests (in JSON).

Would you as a web developer find it easy to develop a website using an image server like this? If so, how would you retrieve and display the images? If not, what would you change about the image server?

This is an open ended question, so I'm just wondering how suitable an image server designed in this way would be for a web developer, and for the application mentioned above.

Comment: So the server always keeps only one original image and you send a request to it to give you that original and then you apply transformations in your website code?

Comment: @CyberDude : Yes, the transformations are sent through the HTTP POST body as JSON.

Comment: So the image server is doing the transformations, not you in the web app?

Comment: @CyberDude : Yes, the image server does all the transformations. The website only displays the transformed images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are shown to endusers via `<img ..../>` tag, which implies `GET` request. For each img `GET` request I would need to do the following:

- analyze `GET` request path and parameters
- generate new `POST` request to the image server
- retrieve image bytes from image server
- create http response with appropriate content-type and length
- send image bytes to enduser

No, I cant say it's an easy solution and it'd be much easier if it were not for such `GET`-`POST`-`GET` conversion.

Comment: If you had control over the image server, what would you change about the way you interface with it in order to accommodate your needs? Would image retrieval through GET instead of POST be enough? Getting an image using one input parameter would be easy enough, but the issue for me was finding a way to pass the parameters for the dynamic manipulation of the image. The request for that can include any number of operations (resize, crop, flip, etc.), and each operation also has its own set of required parameters (e.g. 'resize' needs 'width' and 'height').

Comment: @rafale, yes, being possible to `GET` images would be much easier: I'd modify enduser request (add missing crop, resize, flip or whatever else params) and proxy it to the image server.